# Where can I find linux-backports-modules-wireless-cw package for ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.19?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, backport

[Here is what I've done so far](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801526/no-network-devices-available-ubuntu-14-04-when-wireless-previously-worked) which has the output to many commands for diagnosing the issue. The wifi on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop broke after (I think) this [kernel update I don't remember doing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules).

I've followed the solution in that question and after disabling secure boot, restarting, then running `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` there were no errors and no output. Then I ran dmesg whose output is [here](http://pastebin.com/UtdMdUP9).

The helpful people in #linux pointed me to me needing the linux-backports-modules-wireless-cw package for ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.19, but there were too many matches and we weren't sure which one to download/install. I am hoping for some guidance on this. Thanks.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI. That is probably the reason why the backports does not load. You can also boot with an older kernel version using grub menu. Wi-Fi will work and you will be able to upgrade your kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 SecureBoot is disabled. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` completes without output or error but wifi doesn't work still. How would I get to the grub menu -> use an older kernel version -> upgrade my kernel?

Comment: Get into grub menu when you boot. It depends on the system how to get there. Either Shift or ESC key. Then you can choose one of installed kernels to boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 went back to kernel 3.19.0-64 (before I was on 65) and wifi instantly starts working again. You mentioned I can now upgrade my kernel but wasn't my upgraded kernel the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any backports for Ubuntu 14.04 because there is a new kernel available for this release.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

and new Intel wireless adapters will work.

Comment: The core of the issue was that my wifi would not work no matter what though. I've gone to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/kernel/linux-generic-lts-xenial , is that the right place? What needs to be downloaded onto a usb to bring over to the ubuntu laptop?

Comment: It is easier to connect to internet by some other means. Or you will need to download some kernel packages manually.

Comment: I'm on my windows laptop to get the files since the laptop doesn't have an ethernet port. Do I need both the kernel headers and kernal image files on http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/kernel/linux-generic-lts-xenial?

Comment: You need kernel image and headers packages with dependencies.

Comment: I'm on 3.19.0-64 (1 kernel version lower than before) and wifi is working now. Should I install that package now with apt-get while on -64 then go back to 3.19.0-65 and wifi would still work?